# How can I pass an array to a function that cannot modify it?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, constants

I'm programming in C and I want to pass an array to a function; this function cannot modify the elements of the array. What is the correct syntax for the arguments of the function?

```
void func(const Foo array_in[])
```

or

```
void func(Foo const array_in[])
```

or maybe they are the same? 
Thank you.

Comment: You can't pass array to a function but a pointer to it's first element. Both forms are correct, you can use either.

Comment: Note that qualifying the parameter type with `const` only helps the programmer avoid inadvertently modifying the array elements. If they intentionally cast a pointer to a non-const type and use it to modify the elements, the C standard permits that. So this declaration will not give you situation in which the function **cannot** modify the elements of the array, just one in which it is being suggested or indicated that it should not be doing that.

Comment: @haccks Curious, Re: "You can't pass array to a function but a pointer to it's first element".  With `printf("%f\n", 123.4f);`, do you also say one cannot pass a `float` to `printf()`?  (Given the `float` is converted to a `double` before calling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the declarations `const Foo array_in[]` and `Foo const array_in[]` are exactly the same in C.

Second, when the parameter type of a function has "array of T" type, it is automatically adjusted to "pointer to T" type. So the compiler pretends as if you wrote:

```
void func(const Foo *array_in)
```

or equivalently

```
void func(Foo const *array_in)
```

Note that both `const Foo *array_in` and `Foo const *array_in` mean the exact same thing in C (pointer to const Foo). However, `Foo * const array_in` means something different (const pointer to Foo).

Answer (score 5):

You should use **pointer to constant** in order to handle that:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(const int *ptr)//pointer to constant - array boils down to pointer when passed to function
{
    ptr[0]=9;        //ERROR: Read-Only
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4};

    fun(arr);
    return 0;    
}
```

NOTE: Do not confuse it with **constant pointer**

Comment: Why should they use “pointer to constant”? What is wrong with the declarations in the question?

Comment: `void func(const Foo array_in[])` and `void func(Foo const array_in[])` already use a `pointer to constant`.  This answer is only suggesting a different style.